# What do I select when I do npm start in React native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

[What I am seeing in the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPH6i.png)

What to do from here?

Answer (score 0):

Your question about what you see on the terminal is the start server from Expo
managed workflow if you want to run it you can install an android emulator
https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator
then you can enter key A for Opening android and you will see your app running on Emulator

Comment: what should I choose among the options which are given in the terminal seen in the image?

Comment: if you have android Emulator you can press A on keyboard to start opening your app in emulator or your actual device

Comment: and if my answer was helpful please press that up vote left to my answer

Answer (score 0):

I selected web option then it started showing on my browser on http://localhost:19006/

Earlier it asked me to install some libraries and I clicked yes.